# How to save a .webarchive in UIWebView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview, webarchive

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/04/12/creating-a-document-centric-iphoneipad-application-with-own-file-format-using-ziparchive/) and was wondering how I can save the current webpage as a .webarchive with the code I am using from the tutorial?

Help is very much appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Unlike its Mac counterpart `WebView`, `UIWebView` has no API for creating web archives. It can display webarchives that have been created on the Mac though (e.g. using Save as... in Safari).

Comment: how does Downloads Lite on the App Store save them then and I've also seen a few other apps do the same thing too? There must be a way...

Comment: I didn't say it's impossible, just that `UIWebView` has no built-in API for this. You might find this open source project useful: https://github.com/pokeb/ProxyingUIWebView

Comment: That seems quite complexed :(